# Why does this mongo query return everything less than 60 instead of everything between 50 and 60?

Tags: mongodb

Im taking an online Mongo course. One of the questions they posed there is what would the following query do:

```
db.scores.find( { score : { $gt : 50 }, score : { $lt : 60 } } );
```

My first guess was return all objects where score is between 50 and 60, but the correct answer is return all objects with a score less than 60. Why is that?

Comment: To help understand what's going on, evaluate `query = { score : { $gt : 50 }, score : { $lt : 60 } }` at the MongoDB shell prompt.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ah, good catch. Totally forgot JSON keys have to be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method first argument is a document and `{ "score" : { "$gt" : 50 }, "score" : { "$lt" : 60 } }` is [valid  JSON document](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) but JavaScript overwrites properties that have the same name. So first `score` will be overwritten. The following query is what will return all objects where score is between 50 and 60.

```
db.scores.find( { score : { $gt : 50 ,  $lt : 60 } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you query on a single field, you need to use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), because it return the result of the second expresion, which overides the first.
Try this query as example:

```
db.scores.find({ 
   score : { $gt : 50 }, 
   score : { $lt : 60 }, 
   score : { $lt : 40 } 
})
```

Comment: That doesn't explain OP's  *"why"*